# jquery average image color

Tags: jquery, canvas, rgb

I try to get the average color of an image thanks to a canvas.

I want to calculate the average rgb color for each background-image of the same divs classname.

But I have an error :`TypeError` on line drawImage

I think it's due to my each loop and the way I get my source image url maybe.
It seems that my canvas won't to be drawn.

```
$('.element').each( function(){
    var img = $(this).find('.element-imgT').css('background-image');
    img = img.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('"','');
    var rgb = getAverageRGB(img);
})

function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {
    var blockSize = 5,
        defaultRGB = {r:255,g:255,b:255},
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data, width, height,
        i = -4,
        length,
        rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
        count = 0;  
    if (!context) {
        return defaultRGB;
    }
    height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
    width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;
    context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);
    try {
        data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('alert')
        return defaultRGB;
    } 
    length = data.data.length;
    while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
        ++count;
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
    }
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);
    return rgb;  
}
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsPmR/3/

I don't know what is the way to solve this problem...

EDIT:

NEW WORKING FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/dsPmR/5/ (answer by  Fabrício Matté )

Comment: The function expects an `img` element and you're passing a string.

Comment: ok. But how I can make it work. I try this for example :`img = $('<img src='+url+'>')` but I have the same error on drawImage...

Comment: Even after you fix that, then you will get `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

Comment: I don't see this errors... I always have TypeError

Comment: Because you're passing a jQuery object instead of a DOM img element. Your `try` block catches the other error so you don't see it. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsPmR/4/

Comment: ok. And what are this new errors now?

Comment: if you load images from a different domain into a canvas you can't read its data (due to [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). So fiddle.jshell.net can't access image data from the URLs you've given. This error won't happen if you load images from the same domain as the page you're serving.

Comment: I try on my webserver and it work. However I have this a new error  du to replace function : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined `

Comment: Did you get it working? I've renamed some variables so that was probably it.

Comment: this error is always here...

Comment: Oh I'll check locally then

Comment: It seems to work when I copy-paste all the code from the updated fiddle in the question and use an image from the same domain. Can you point to which line gives the error?

Comment: it's `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined ` on line 3 `var url = bgImg.replace(/^url\(["']?|["']?\)$/g, '');` on google chrome

Comment: Make sure `$(this).find('.element-imgT')` finds some element. That's probably the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that a string was being passed to `getAverageRGB` which expects [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

You can create an image element, wait for it to load (so that `getAverageRGB` can properly read the image data) then pass it to the function.

```
$('.element').each( function(){
    var bgImg = $(this).find('.element-imgT').css('background-image');
    var url = bgImg.replace(/^url\(["']?|["']?\)$/g, '');

    // Setting load handler before the src property as an extra caution
    // against cached resources
    $('<img>').load(function() {
        var rgb = getAverageRGB(this);
        console.log(rgb);
    }).prop('src', url);
});
```

Note: this method may not work for images from different domains. The good old [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will block the `getImageData` from reading image data from canvases that contain resources which do not satisfy the same origin policy rules.